# Why is save not working with mockdomain in Grails?

Tags: grails, grails-orm

Does anybody know how I can get mockDomain to work in JUnit Tests?

The following test fails:

```
void testRoleSave()
{
    def roles = []
    mockDomain(Role, roles)

    Role role = new Role(authority: "baba");
    role.save(flush: true, failOnError: true)

    println role.errors
    assertNotNull(role.id)
    println role.id
    assertEquals(Role.getAll().size(), 1)
    //assertEquals(roles.size(), 1)


}
```

Error:

```
junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: expected:<0> but was:<1>
    at ....testRoleSave(ReceiveMailControllerTests.groovy:36)
```

Comment: `assertEquals` should have opposite order of parameters: first expected, then actual.

Answer (score 1):

use Role.list() or Role.count() instead of Role.getAll().